# How to access an inner ItemsControl in a ListBox in Windows Phone Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox, selecteditem

I am building a small Windows Phone application which has a databound `ListBox` as a main control. `DataTemplate` of that `ListBox` is a databound `ItemsControl` element, which shows when a person taps on a `ListBox` element.

Currently, I am accessing it by traversing the visual tree of the application and referencing it in a list, and than getting the selected item through `SelectedIndex` property.

Is there a better or more effective way?

This one works **currently**, but I am afraid if it would stay effective in case of larger lists.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried wiring the `SelectionChanged` event of the ListBox?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- ... -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

With this in the code behind:

```
private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;

    // nothing selected? ignore
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
         // something is selected
    }

    // unselect the item so if they press it again, it takes the selection
    listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: I have, but that gives me only the selected index, and not the inner item of a DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBoxItem item = this.lstItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(yourIndex) as ListBoxItem;
```

Then you can use the VisualTreeHelper class to get the sub items

```
var containerBorder = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, 0) as Border;
var contentControl = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(containerBorder, 0);
var contentPresenter = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentControl, 0);
var stackPanel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(contentPresenter, 0) as StackPanel; // Here the UIElement root type of your item template, say a stack panel for example.
var lblLineOne = stackPanel.Children[0] as TextBlock; // Child of stack panel
lblLineOne.Text = "Some Text"; // Updating the text.
```

Another option is to use services of the GestureServices class available in the WP7 Toolkit.

You'll need to add a GestureListner to the Root Element of your DataTemplate like so:

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Controls:GestureService.GestureListener>
                            <Controls:GestureListener Tap="GestureListener_Tap" />
                        </Controls:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="lblLineOne" Text="{Binding LineOne}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And in the GestureListener_Tap event handler, you use this snippet.

```
    private void GestureListener_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var itemTemplateRoot = sender as StackPanel;
        var lbl1 = itemTemplateRoot.Children[0] as TextBlock;
        MessageBox.Show(lbl1.Text);
    }
```

I'm not sure how the GestureListner recognize internally the item being tapped but I guess that it uses the VisualTreeHelper, at least this method is more concise.

Comment: This would basically be a similar method to traversing a tree, I would only be doing it at the moment when someone clicks on an item?

Comment: So you'll need to use GestureListner class from the toolkit to handle the item being selected, I made a small snippet above, hope this helps